# Does a Django site need a Postgres database when hosting on Heroku? Can I remove the Postgres add-on?

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a website that I built using Django and deployed on Heroku. The tutorial I followed had me set up a Heroku Postgres database attached as an add-on. After Heroku's recent pricing changes the Postgres database has gone from free to $5 / month.

Maybe static isn't the correct word, but the site doesn't have user accounts, collect user information, or otherwise have any need for a database. I believe the only information that's stored in the database is login info for the Django admin site. I was able to export a .pgdmp file from Heroku of the data stored in the database but couldn't make heads or tails of the contents.

Here's the `settings.py` file code for the database section:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

My question is can I delete this add-on from the Heroku CLI or dashboard without breaking the site in production? Would I need to change anything in my `settings.py` file or elsewhere in my Django code first? I assume I would still be able to access the Django admin page on the development server, is that assumption correct?

Sorry for the possibly obvious question but I just don't want to break a site in production without doing some research first!

Answer (score 0):

> My question is can I delete this add-on from the Heroku CLI or dashboard without breaking the site in production?

We can't know for sure, but probably not.

You are using [`dj-database-url`](https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/) to set your default database. That likely means that your application is connecting to PostgreSQL via the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

SQLite does not work properly on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). If you need a database, it needs to be a client-server database instead of a file-based database.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, I realize it's a difficult question to answer with so little context and you are correct dj-database-url is how I'm currently connecting to the database. But I guess my question is does a Django site inherently need a database to function when hosted in production? Maybe if it's easier to answer then assume barebones, just a skeleton of a Django site.

Comment: @jbothner21, it really depends on what the site does. Have you defined models? Do they get saved to and / or loaded from somewhere? Lots of third-party Django modules will assume that you have a database and provide their own models, and there are often dependencies on things like [the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/sites/) that do require a database. But I believe it would be possible to create a basic static site without a database...

Comment: @jbothner21, it's probably worth connecting to your database to see what is currently in it, if anything. One easy way to do that is via Heroku's [dataclips feature](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips#quickstart). Or, you could connect the database client of your choice.

Comment: No I know for sure I haven't defined any models. I have an empty models.py file in my project. In hindsight I probably should have built this with something more lightweight like Flask but I wasn't aware of the differences when I started. The dataclips feature was a great suggestion! It looks like I have 11 tables such as django_migrations, auth_user, django_session, django_site, etc. My guess is this data doesn't update often but it's still necessary for functionality. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in my situation finding this in the future here's what I learned:

My initial hypothesis was correct, deleting the Postgres Heroku add-on left the site in production intact and working correctly. The only difference without the database is I can't access the Django admin page on the hosted site but I can still access this through the development server if needed.

Your site might be different than mine however, so your mileage may vary. Here's a couple things I did before making any changes to the site in production.

1. Check what tables/data you have in your database. Thanks to @Chris who answered in this thread and posted this link talking about the [dataclips feature in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips#quickstart). If you have tables that seem not to relate to the admin interface then you might be reliant on your database.
2. Consider spinning up another instance of your live site in production on Heroku. This way you can test and make changes without impacting users on the live site if something goes wrong.